# Immutable.JS replacing last item in array instead of appending

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm using Immutable JS in my redux application and attempting to update the array that exists in my object, I can only add one item before it gets replaced after each subsequent add.

```
/**************
INITIAL STATE
***************/
const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable.fromJS({
  budgetCategories: [
    {budgetName: 'budgetName', monthlyCost: '$200.00', rollOverEnabled: true, dueDate: 'monthly'}
  ]
});

/**************
TYPES
***************/
export const ADD_BUDGET = 'src/Budget/ADD_BUDGET';

/**************
REDUCER LOGIC FLOW
***************/
export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_BUDGET:
      console.log("Payload is:");
      console.log(action.payload);
      return INITIAL_STATE.updateIn(['budgetCategories'], arr => arr.push(Immutable.fromJS(action.payload)))
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

## Example:

State:

```
Index 0:
    budgetName(pin): "rwer"
    monthlyCost(pin): "tryrtyt"
    rollOverEnabled(pin): false
    dueDate(pin): "Sat, 06 Jan 2018 17:24:44 GMT"
```

Running through the reducer function and changing budgetName only will yield:

```
Index 0:
    budgetName(pin): "changedBudgetName"
    monthlyCost(pin): "tryrtyt"
    rollOverEnabled(pin): false
    dueDate(pin): "Sat, 06 Jan 2018 17:24:44 GMT"
```

As you can see, this code overrides the index.

Comment: Hey @Rayan, try this: return state.updateIn(['budgetCategories'], arr => arr.push(Immutable.fromJS(action.payload))) ?

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you

Comment: that's nice ! @Rayan

Comment: @LefiTarik please add an answer instead of a comment. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

return the **state** instead of the **INITIAL_STATE**:

```
return state.updateIn(['budgetCategories'], arr =>
  arr.push(Immutable.fromJS(action.payload))
);
```